# Rheological behavior of chocolate

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics

If someone eats chocolate, the chocolate goes through the following configurations:

$\chi_0:$ chocolate is solid and has a smooth Surface everywhere; the Riemann Tensor vanishes on every Point of the chocolate, i.e. $R_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}=0$.

$\chi_1:$ chocolate is solid but due to chewing it is splitted into different pieces; it holds $R_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} \neq 0$ and moreover the curvature Tensor is not defined in the positions in which the geometry is non-continuous.

$\chi_2:$ chocolate is liquid and it is impossible to define any curvature Tensor.

Continuum mechanics is a discipline that tries to create models for rheological materials like chocolate. The question is not about finding a material equation (a material equation is an equation that links e.g. the stress Tensor to Deformation gradient, etc.) for chocolate. It is a geometrical question: Can one use some mathematical techniques to define a Riemann curvature Tensor on the chocolate continuum even if there are discontinuities and moreover a loss of a solid geometry?

I am thinking about the following: I try to define a "Connection equation" for the vector $e_\mu$ (for simplicity, Torsion is neglected). These I am trying to define:

$\partial_{\nu}e_{\mu} + \hat{\Sigma}_{\nu \mu}^\alpha e_\alpha = 0$.

The Expression $\hat{\Sigma}_{\nu \mu}^\alpha$ is not a real number; it is an Operator. The Operator also can generate discontinuous changes in $e_\mu$. Moreover, I am thinking about using Itô calculus, since the liquid chocolate can be assumed as a manifold where randomness Tangent spaces occur. The Connection is a random (and also random noise) variable such that irregular and non-continuous parts of the manifold are respected.

Question: Is my idea sounding serious? Are there ever used some generalized differential-geometric concepts like this?

Every reply will be highly appreciated.